# Solr - Field with default value resets itself if it is stored=false

Tags: java, solr, configuration

I am having a weird problem with Solr (4.x) when I set a field to stored=false and give it a default value. To make everything clear, my schema is something like:

```
<field name="field1" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="field2" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="field3" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="field4" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="field5" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="false" default="0" />
```

And by default each document has a field5=0 at the beginning. Then I update documents, and set field5=1 for some documents. And in case I update the documents which has field5=1, they all goes back to field5=0. But when field5 is stored=true, then there is no problem, they are never going back to default value, although there is no updates on that field...

any solution to overcome this? I can keep the field stored=true of course but then it will cause the index get bigger hence slowing down the search because of overhead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the update operation retrieves the **stored** value of the fields and reindexes the whole new entity. So, if the field is not marked as stored, you cannot use it with atomic update. Usually, unstored fields would just disappear, the interplay with default value is unusual.

I would not worry about performance at this stage of index design, especially if it is for numbers. There is all sorts of optimization under the covers you can use later and the bottleneck may not be where you expect.

Comment: so it is better to make all of the fields stored=true.. i was switched some of them to false, as i dont need to retrieve them to show to the end user, but with this problem, it doesnt make any sense to keep them false... so with atomic updates stored option becomes some kinda bug if the field has default value? some kinda annoying

Comment: You don't need to show all your fields to the user. There are parameters for that (**fl**). You can also turn lazy loading on to avoid even loading them into the memory normally. You have some optimization options, if you look.

Atomic Update is something that is hard in the underlying Lucene architecture and is this implementation is the current trade-off for the fast search. That's why you see what you see.

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered the same issue. 
Update feature in SOLR requires all fields to be stored "TRUE" as SOLR uses stored fields to get data from them and then uses this data to reconstruct the document that will be removed and indexed again.